# how to simplify the length of the state in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state

```
import { OrderSummary } from "@/services/order/data";
```

Below is my state declaration

```js
let [orderSummary, setOrderSummary] = useState<OrderSummaryResponse>({
    Id: 0,
    TableId: 0,
    TableName: '',
    MerchantId: 0,
    StoreId: 0,
    StoreName: '',
    BrandName: '',
    IsUnifyQR: false,
    Discount: 0,
    ServiceCharge: 0,
    GST: 0,
    RoundingAdjustment: 0,
    TotalAmount: 0,
    SubTotalAmount: 0,
    ServiceChargeAmount: 0,
    GSTAmount: 0,
    CreatedAt: '',
    Items: [
        {
            MerchantId: 0,
            StoreId: 0,
            StoreName: '',
            ItemId: 0,
            ProductId: 0,
            ProductName: '',
            TotalAmount: 0,
            Quantity: 0,
            Note: '',
            Choices: [
                {
                    OptionSelectedName: '',
                    ProductOptionId: 0,
                    OptionSelected: null,
                    MultiOptionsSelected: null,
                    OneChoiceWithValueSelected: {
                        OptionSelected: 0,
                        Quantity: 0,
                        Price: 0,
                    },
                    MultioptionWithValueSelected: [],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
    Categories: [''],
});
```

if I have a few `usestate` like above, my code looks very lengthy how to simplify that.

getting error if I use like this

```
let [orderSummary, setOrderSummary] = useState<OrderSummary>({})
```

Comment: Is your `OrderSummary` a type or an actual object?

Answer (score 2):

```
let [orderSummary, setOrderSummary] = useState<OrderSummary>({} as any)
```

Comment: above code is working, but getting error when i get some details from the response (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
) when i try to get like this - ```orderSummary.Items.length```, if i comment this part its working, but i need to check the items. length

Comment: you should use optional chaining to access your property, such as orderSummary.Items?.length to prevent orderSummary or orderSummary.items is null or undefined.

Comment: that's because orderSummary has no items property before api fetch is completed.

Comment: The alternative is to set initial values ​​for the properties you will use first, like this `let [orderSummary, setOrderSummary] = useState<OrderSummary>({ Items: [] } as any)`

Comment: ```useState<OrderSummary>({ Items: [] } as any)``` - is working Thank You...

Comment: @mohanm nice, could you upvote and set my post as accept answer? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type like this:

```
let [orderSummary, setOrderSummary] = useState<OrderSummary | null>(null)
```

And when you want to use `orderSummary`. You can add `optional chaining` like this:

```
orderSummary?.StoreId
```

Comment: if i use the above code getting error- 
- Property 'StoreId' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: its i m getting the same @Viet

Comment: now getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'StoreId' of null", i followed the below code, now its working, thank you for your support.